# create user based on the loggedin user access token in jmeter and assign different access rights to each user through csv in jmeter

Tags: csv, jmeter, stress-testing

I am using JMeter to stress and load test our application developed in MVC framework. Our application is developed in REST API's.

I created scripts for logging in, creating users and orders through CSV file.

I have got the following issues:

1. I need to **assign different access rights to each user** through CSV. how can I do that in JMeter ?
2. Create, edit or delete account based on the logged-in user's access token.

Is it possible in JMeter? How can I achieve these in JMeter?

CSV file screenshot that i am using:

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

I believe [Switch Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Switch_Controller) is something you're looking for, you can point JMeter to execute this or that switch branch basing on `Operation` variable value

You can find an example of Switch Controller usage in the [Running JMeter Samplers with Defined Percentage Probability](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/running-jmeter-samplers-defined-percentage-probability) article.

Comment: For that i need to write script for each user with different permissions thus increases more manual work. can i not do it within the one script using switch controller?